# Content is saved and published, but status displays as 'none'

Tags: bolt-cms

I've created some content with this:

```
$empty->values['id'] = (isset($exists[0]->id)) ? $exists[0]->id : null;
$empty->values['name'] = $video->name;
$empty->values['vimeo_id'] = $video->vimeo_id;
$empty->values['description'] = ($video->description != null) ? $video->description : '';
$empty->values['created_time'] = $video->created_time;
$empty->values['modified_time'] = $video->modified_time;
$empty->values['embed_html'] = $video->embed_html;
$empty->values['status'] = 'publish';

$updated = $this->app['storage']->saveContent($empty);
```

And when I visit the backend I can see that it's created but the status is 'none' - see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dULTg.png).

Answer (score 0):

The status should be "published" in the current release of bolt.